# How can I open a file with a specific application and another file of the same file type with another application?

Tags: files, default-programs, file-format

**Example:**

The content of my book is stored in `book.md`. I want to write my book in [Typora.io](http://www.typora.io/).

The content of my presentation is stored in `presentation.md`. I want to work on my presentation in [Ghostwriter](http://wereturtle.github.io/ghostwriter/).

Answer (score 2):

You could call them from the terminal and make an alias for each command...

```
/path/to/typora /path/to/book.md & disown
/path/to/ghostwriter /path/to/presentation.md & disown
```

(if `typora` and `ghostwriter` are in your PATH, you can just use `typora /path/to/book.md` etc)

if you like, discard any output

```
/path/to/typora /path/to/book.md >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

make an alias in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias edit-book='/path/to/typora /path/to/book.md >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown'
```

And one for the presentation

```
alias edit-present='/path/to/ghostwriter /path/to/presentation.md >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown'
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for opening these files from the Unity Dash?

Comment: @RobertOrzanna possibly - you can make a launcher with the command. I use MATE so I can enter `mate-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop --create-new` in a terminal to create a new launcher - you can try replacing `mate` with `gnome`. In the launcher dialog, put you desired name and in the command field `/path/to/desired/program /path/to/desired/file` then choose an icon and when the launcher appears drag it onto the panel? If this works I will add to my answer. Works for me in MATE...

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a more generic solution. Imagine you would want to to this for a number of files. Creating launchers becomes cumbersome. I hoped there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Well... @RobertOrzanna maybe there is, and I'm just lacking imagination and knowledge about setting default program for a specific file rather than for a file type

Comment: Maybe something to think about for the future of Ubuntu. :-)